# CORS issue in Spring Boot + Spring Data Rest Repositories annotated with @CrossOrigin

Tags: java, spring, cors, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I am having an issue with my spring boot + spring data rest application due to CORS.
This application exposes endpoints automatically created using `@RepositoryRestResource` on the `JpaRepository` interface.

This is one example:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
   ....
}
```

Unfortunately, I am not getting the expected Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response.
Instead I am getting this header using Postman:

[image]

I also tried configuring CORS in the `RepositoryRestConfigurer`:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringDataRestCustomization implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
    config.getCorsRegistry()
        .addMapping("/**")
      .allowedOrigins("*")
      .allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "DELETE")
      .exposedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
      .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(3600);
  }
}
```

Anybody having the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

Issue resolved!

I realised that you need to include the header "Origin" inside your request.
If not, the response returned will not contain the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Stupid mistake but maybe it could avoid wasting time for somebody else. :)